# Delete lines from file using sed containing different patterns

Tags: shell, sed

I have a dump from a production DB but i want to remove data of some tables like messages, messages_files, etc because are not useful to debug/programming  on local.

I have been using this command to remove the lines containing this kind of data:

```
sed -i '/CREATE DATABASE/d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/USE \`okn/d' $current_main_db.sql && 
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql && 
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_email_cron\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_users\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_files\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_mail_list\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_sms_cron\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_tags\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_temp_receivers\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql &&
sed -i '/INSERT INTO \`messages_threads\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql;
```

It works well but is very slow so i try to combine all the patterns into one `sed` command. I read the manual and find this:

> regexp1\|regexp2
>
> Matches either regexp1 or regexp2. Use parentheses to use complex alternative regular expressions. The matching process tries each alternative in turn, from left to right, and the first one that succeeds is used. It is a GNU extension.

So i tried this:

```
sed -i '/CREATE DATABASE\|USE \`okn\|INSERT INTO \`messages\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_email_cron\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_users\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_files\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_mail_list\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_sms_cron\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_tags\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_temp_receivers\`\|INSERT INTO \`messages_threads\`/ d' $current_main_db.sql;
```

But do not work, i tried to use parenthesis for every pattern without any luck:

```
sed -i '/(CREATE DATABASE\|USE \`okn)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_email_cron\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_users\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_files\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_mail_list\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_sms_cron\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_tags\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_temp_receivers\`)\|(INSERT INTO \`messages_threads\`)/d'
```

Am i doing something wrong?

I search in SO and find some similar questions but do not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` should suffice:

```
grep -vE '^(INSERT INTO `messages(_email_cron|_users|_files|_mail_list|_sms_cron|_tags|_temp_receivers|_threads)`|CREATE DATABASE|USE `okn)' file
```

Comment: Doesn't work, i execute command redirecting to another file and both files has the same weight

Comment: @Sal00m: are SQL commands at the start of the line or there are leading spaces? (in this case remove the anchor `^` or better change it to `^[ \t]*`)

Comment: @Sal00m: It was a stupid typo, I added a slash at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the parenthesis as well:

```
sed -i '/\(CREATE DATABASE\)\|\(USE \`okn\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_email_cron\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_users\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_files\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_mail_list\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_sms_cron\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_tags\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_temp_receivers\`\)\|\(INSERT INTO \`messages_threads\`\)/d'
```

Comment: Same, the lines aren't deleted :(

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is slow because you start a new sed instance for every command. And your regexp is complicated because you try to handle all expressions at once. There is a compromise solution, however

```
sed '/pattern1/d; /pattern2/d; ...'
```

Also note that you can simplify your regular expression as demonstrated by @CasimirEtHippolyte.